# Attribute Error in Uploading Excel File to Django

Tags: django, excel, python-3.x, file-upload

I am having trouble uploading excel file to my django application. It is a very simple application that should allow a user to upload an excel file with 3 columns. The application will read the contents of this file and process it into bunch of calculations

here is my **forms.py**:

```
class InputForm(forms.Form):
FileLocation = forms.FileField(label='Import Data',required=True,widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': ".xlsx"}))
```

**settings.py**:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = ["django_excel.ExcelMemoryFileUploadHandler",
                    "django_excel.TemporaryExcelFileUploadHandler"]
```

**views.py**:

```
import xlrd
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, render
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from io import TextIOWrapper
from WebApp.forms import *
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.db import connection
import os
import csv
def analyze(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST,request.FILES['FileLocation'])


     if form.is_valid():
         book = xlrd.open_workbook(request.FILES('FileLocation'))
         for sheet in book.sheets():
             number_of_rows = sheet.nrows
             number_of_columns = sheet.ncols
             print(number_of_rows)
```

I upload the file in the form and it gives me an error:

```
    AttributeError at /app/analyze/

    'ExcelInMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'get'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/data/analyze/
Django Version:     1.11
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

Exception Location:     C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py in value_from_datadict, line 367
    Python Executable:  C:\Python36\python.exe
    Python Version:     3.6.4
```

I am also able to upload a .csv file successfully using the following views.py code:

```
def analyze(request):
    c={}
    context = RequestContext(request)
    c.update(csrf(request))
    abc=['a','b','c']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        dataType = request.POST.get("DataType")
        print(dataType)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data            #print (cd)

            a =  TextIOWrapper(request.FILES['FileLocation'].file,encoding='ascii',errors='replace')

        #print (request.FILES.keys())
        data = csv.reader(a)
        row1csv = next(data)
        region = row1csv[0]
        metric = row1csv[2]
```

I have tried django-excel with same error.

Comment: I think it would help to show the code for `InputForm`, seems that's where the problem is.

Comment: Also this code is wrong: `book = xlrd.open_workbook(request.FILES('FileLocation'))`, it should be square brackets for `request.FILES['FileLocation']`. But that's a different error, it's not going to produce the error in the form's widget.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing. (1) Do you mean the HTML code for InputForm? (2) I tried changing my code to `request.FILES['FileLocation']` in the statement. Same error.

Comment: yep, as I said, your error is not related to the square brackets, however you'd get a new error after you fix the first :-) Sorry, my bad, missed the `InputForm` code at the top.

Comment: You're not correctly initialising the form: `form = InputForm(request.POST, request.FILES['FileLocation'])` should be `form = InputForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`. It's expecting a dictionary  (QueryDict) here, not an uploaded file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correctly initialising your form for the .CSV case but not in your Excel case:

```
form = InputForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Don't initialise using `request.FILES['FileLocation']` as that's passing the wrong type to the form. It's expecting a MultiValueDict of uploaded files, not a single uploaded file. That's why it fails when calling `get` on it.

Next, you can't pass an `ExcelInMemoryUploadedFile` to `xlrd.get_workbook()`. You need to save the file to disk first, then pass it's path to the `get_workbook()` method. The [documentation](http://django.pyexcel.org/en/latest/#api-reference) of django-excel gives some easier methods:

```
book = request.FILES['FileLocation'].get_book()  # note the square brackets!
```

or to directly access a sheet:

```
sheet = request.FILES['FileLocation'].get_sheet('sheet1')
```

Comment: I tried that change in `request.FILES`. I got the next error: `expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not MultiValueDict`

Comment: what?? that's very strange. on which line is it giving this error? can you show the full trace? I expect such error on a different place in your code, probably the `book = xlrd.open_workbook(request.FILES['FileLocation'])` line

Comment: `book = xlrd.open_workbook(request.FILES)
C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py in open_workbook
            with open(filename, "rb") as f:`
I think error is in the `xlrd.openworkbook` line
`file_contents  
filename  
{'FileLocation': <ExcelInMemoryUploadedFile: filename.xlsx (application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet)>}
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>`

Comment: `xlrd.open_workbook()` is expecting a path or byte stream, you can't pass it your `request.FILES` or `request.FILES['FileLocation']`. Check the documentation of xlrd. Save the file to disk that was uploaded first, then pass the path of the file to `xlrd.open_workshop()`.

Comment: There seems to be a function `get_book()` and `get_sheet()` for the `ExcelMixin`, so you can fetch `book = request.FILES['FileLocation'].get_book()` directly on the uploaded file object. See [here](http://django.pyexcel.org/en/latest/#api-reference)

Comment: yes, ExcelMixin worked very well. Prior suggestions on `book = request.FILES['FileLocation'].get_book() ` works and `book = request.FILES['FileLocation'].get_sheet()`  many thanks for helping me out.